# HERE Navstreets LINK_ID Range

Tags: here-api, uniqueidentifier

My organization has acquired the HERE Navstreets data set. It wishes to update the content while still adhering to the HERE Navstreets data model and relationships.

In this context, it is deemed of value to:

1. Retain the LINK_ID column as the unique identifier for each street segment.
2. Make a distinction between the original HERE LINK_ID values and the one added by my organization.
3. Retain the ability to ingest streets updates from HERE should my organization decide to do so.

In this context, we would like to use a different range of LINK_ID values from the one used by HERE. As an example, if HERE uses values between 10,000,000 and 100,000,000, we would assign only LINK_ID values that are within the range 1,000-9,999,999 (this is only for illustration purposes).

Is this approach already accounted for by HERE for the street data they may get from Map Creator? Is there a specific HERE (for Review or Work in Progress) range of LINK_ID values we should consider?

Answer (score 0):

Based on the **HERE KB0015682**: Permanent ID concept in HERE Data

**Entities with Permanent IDs**

Generally, the following feature do have permanent IDs in the HERE Map products:

- Lane
- Face
- Point Features
- Administrative Areas (for , Built-up Areas, Districts, and Administrative Areas)
- Complex Features (this includes Complex Administrative Area Features as well as Complex Intersections and Complex Roads)

Permanent IDs are globally unique within a specific Object, e.g., a Link ID occurs once globally. However the same Permanent ID can be used among different Object types (e.g., Node, Link, condition, etc.). Note: When a map is upgraded to Intermediate or HERE map, or when a country undergoes administrative restructuring, there may be a change in Permanent IDs.

The following are examples of permanent IDs in the RDF:

- Address Point ID
- Admin Place ID
- Association ID
- Building ID
- Carto ID
- Complex Feature ID
- Condition ID
- Country ID (which is one of the Admin Place IDs)
- Face ID
- Feature Point ID
- Lane ID
- Lane Nav Strand ID
- Link ID
- Name ID (with some exceptions)
- Nav Strand ID
- Node ID
- POI ID
- Road Link ID
- Sign ID
- Zone ID

**Numeric Range of Permanent IDs**

Map object IDs (PVIDs) in the extracts use 32-bit integer values to fit in a N(10) scheme. Note: Exception to N(10) scheme can exist. For example, Lane ID is N(12) in length.

The entire range is divided as follows:

**Range**----------------------------**Designation**

0000000001 to 0016777215 -> Non-permanent IDs

0016777215 to 2147483647 -> Permanent IDs

The range dedicated to permanent IDs are used for any entity.
The range dedicated to non permanent IDs are used in rare situations where an update is made in a copy of the database instead of in the live database itself and this update results in a new ID. This new ID in the database copy would be in the non-permanent range. The update would also be applied into the live database and this update would receive a permanent ID available in the next scheduled release. A cross-reference is not provided between non-permanent IDs and the eventual permanent ID from the live database.